# How to get count of images stored in SD card in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, sd-card

I am using `camera demo` given in `Blackberry sample project`.
Using that I am `saving images in SD Card`, as Image0, Image1, Image2 and so on..
What i want to do , show all images in gallery kind of module in my app.
With two buttons, previous and next.
For that i need to get count of images stored in SD card.
Please tell me how  to do that.

Answer (score 0):

As i stopped working on BB,Sorry for not giving the code.But I Guess

[FileConnectionApi](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.2api/javax/microedition/io/file/FileConnection.html)  with [list enumeration](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.2api/javax/microedition/io/file/FileConnection.html#list%28%29) will resolves you problem.

And more even list [enumeration with filter argument](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.2api/javax/microedition/io/file/FileConnection.html#list%28java.lang.String,%20boolean%29).

description of filter argument is

> filter - String against which all files and directories are matched for retrieval. An asterisk ("*") can be used as a wildcard to represent 0 or more occurrences of any character.